# Bot replies to itself whenever it sends a message

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code so far token is my bot token
My issue is that the bot replies to itself whenever it sends the message

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
print("Test Success")
msg = message.content
member = message.author.id
print(message.author.id)
if member == "":
    print("bot replied to itself ggs worlds ending")
    return
if "" in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('Shut Up', mention_author=True)
    return
client.run(token)
```

Comment: Check to make sure the author of the message is not the bot with an if-condition. Possibly something like if(msg.author.id != <bot-id>){}

Comment: Sorry Im braindead what do you mean by the bot with an if condition?

Comment: I edited my original comment -- let me know if that helps

Comment: How could I get the bot id ?

Comment: Okay so I figured it out I think I did if member == message.author.id: and the if check worked member == message.author.id

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the author of the message in order to possibly exclude the bot.

**A simple method could be:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return # Do not check the bots messages
    else:
        # Do what you want to do
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) calls out that this will happen and recommends

> If you want the bot to not reply to itself, consider checking the user IDs

You can do:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

As suggested in the [Quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Comment: Glad to hear it :) If an answer helped you it can be upvoted with the up arrow at the top left and if it provided the solution you needed then it can be accepted as the answer by clicking the tick beneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the sender of the message is the bot.
I would recommend you to compare the ids

```
# Check if member is bot
if member.id == bot.id:
```